# Can we time commands deterministically?

Tags: bash, time, cpu-cycles

We know that in bash, `time foo` will tell us how long a command foo takes to execute.  But there is so much variability, depending on unrelated factors including what else is running on the machine at the time.  It seems like there should be some deterministic way of measuring how long a program takes to run.  Number of processor cycles, perhaps? Number of pipeline stages?

Is there a way to do this, or if not, to at least get a more meaningful time measurement?

Comment: that's the "real" value (in time command's output) i guess -OR you can run it 100 times and take the average of that "real" .....value?

Comment: No you cannot. A lot of factors add non-determinism: scheduling of other processes, context switching, I/O... If on Linux read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've stumbled into a problem that's (much) harder than it appears. The performance of a program is absolutely connected to the current state of the machine in which it is running. This includes, but is not limited to:

- The contents of all CPU caches.
- The current contents of system memory, including any disk caching.
- Any other processes running on the machine and the resources they're currently using.
- The scheduling decisions the OS makes about where and when to run your program.
- ...the list goes on and on.

If you want a truly repeatable benchmark, you'll have to take explicit steps to control for all of the above. This means flushing caches, removing interference from other programs, and controlling how your job gets run. This isn't an easy task, by any means.

The good news is that, depending on what you're looking for, you might be able to get away with something less rigorous. If you run the job on your regular workload and it produces results in a good amount of time, then that might be all that you need.